# Vimwiki open specific diary on vim startup with bash alias

Tags: plugin-vimwiki

I am trying to figure out how to open a specific vimwiki diary on opening vim.
With one wiki I use an alias like
`alias todo='vim -c VimwikiDiaryIndex'`
which works perfectly.

But now I want an additional diary wiki for another set of notes. I already added the path and can change the diary inside of vim with
`2<Leader>wi`.

But I don't know how to combine it with my alias commands. (Something like `-c 2VimwikiDiaryIndex` does not work.

Does someone know how I could get it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing here but it seems you are trying to run normal mode mappings in batch mode (IOW, `vim -c <cmd>`). Your `2wi` ... I'm assuming that refers to `[count]<Leader>wi`, a VimWiki mapped command in the docs...?

To run such mappings you need to use the `norm` command (`:h :norm`).

For example, `vim -c 'norm 2\wi'` if  your Leader key is the default `\` (backslash).

BTW, if you want to run multiple commands using this method just use a separate `-c` for each. Example:

```
vim -c 'norm 2\wi' -c 'wq'
```

Comment: You need to.use `:normal` and not `:normal!` here, since `:normal!` doesn't expand mappings. From [`:help :normal`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Anormal): *"If the `[!]` is given, mappings will not be used."* Otherwise, answer looks good.

Comment: Yeah, I know and that's how I tested it: `vim -c 'e /tmp/b' -c 'norm G /1' -c 'wq'`. Lord knows why in between there and here I decided subconsciously to add some bangs :P

Comment: @filbranden Thanks for the heads up, btw.

Comment: Working as hoped. Thanks. @fillbranden: also thanks for highlighting the code parts of my answer. Could not find the option while writing on my smartphone .

Answer (score 0):

Add a function like this to you `~/.bashrc`:

```
function vimwikidiary() {
  vim -c "VimwikiIndex $1" -c VimwikiDiaryIndex
}
```

If you run with no arguments of with argument `1`, this will open the diary index of the first wiki:

```
$ vimwikidiary
$ vimwikidiary 1
```

If you run with argument `2`, this will open the diary index of your second wiki:

```
$ vimwikidiary 2
```